# Template specialization for SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I have been working with templates for quite some time now but recently I encountered a weird template programming for SFINAE. 
My question is why do we write 
`typename = {something}` as a template parameter in C++?

Comment: @cplusplusrat the point is that it's an unnamed parameter, needed only to test sunstitution (the S in SFINAE).

Comment: @n.m. but how exactly does it test for substitution? Whatever i write after =  will be evaluated at compile time and will assign the default value to Typename. And so if i am not calling the second parameter in my driver code, then it will take the default value..so my question is can you give an example where the substitution fails at compile time

Comment: As written, this is really overly broad. Do you have a specific example in mind you want to ask about? Default arguments have lots of uses...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is simply how SFINAE works ;)

As you know, you have to "create a failure" within the template declaration and not inside the template definition. As this:

```
template < typename X, typename = ... here is the code which may generate an error     during instantiation >
void Bla() {}
```

The only chance to put some "code" in the declaration is to define something in the template parameter list or inside the template function declaration itself like:

```
template < typename X>
void Bla( ... something which may generates an error ) {}
```

Example:

```
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t< std::is_same_v< int, T>>>
void Bla()
{
    std::cout << "with int" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t< !std::is_same_v< int, T>>>
void Bla(int=0)
{
    std::cout << "with something else" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Bla<int>();
    Bla<std::string>();
}
```

But what is the background of "creating an substitution failure" here?

The trick is somewhere behind `std::enable_if`. We can also use it without that:

```
template <typename T, typename = char[ std::is_same_v< int, T>]>
void Bla()
{   
    std::cout << "with int" << std::endl;
}   

template <typename T, typename = char[ !std::is_same_v< int, T>]>
void Bla(int=0)
{   
    std::cout << "with something else" << std::endl;
}
```

Take a look on: `typename = char[ !std::is_same_v< int, T>]`
Here `std::is_same_v` gives us a bool value back which is casted to 0 if not valid and to any postive number if valid. And creating a `char[0]` is simply an error in c++! So with the negation of our expression with `!` we got one for "is int" and one for "is not int". Once it tries to create an array of size 0, which is a failure and the template will not be instantiated and once it generates the type `char[!0]` which is a valid expression.

And as the last step:

```
... typename = ...
```

is meant as: there will be defined a type, here without a template parameter name, as the parameter itself is not used later. You also can write:

```
... typename X = ...
```

but as X is not used, leave it!

Summary: You have to provide some code, which generates an error or not, depending on the type or value of a given expression. The expression must be part of the function declaration or part of the template parameter list. It is *not* allowed to put an error inside the function/class definition, as this will not longer be "not an error" in the sense of SFINAE.

Update: Can the results of SFINAE expressions be used for further expressions: Yes

Example:

```
    template < typename TYPE >
void CheckForType()
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

    template <typename T, typename X = std::enable_if_t< std::is_same_v< int, T>, float>>
void Bla()
{
    std::cout << "with int" << std::endl;
    CheckForType<X>();
}

    template <typename T, typename X = std::enable_if_t< !std::is_same_v< int, T>, double >>
void Bla(int=0)
{
    std::cout << "with something else" << std::endl;
    CheckForType<X>();
}

int main()
{
    Bla<int>();
    Bla<std::string>();
}
```

Output:

```
with int
void CheckForType() [with TYPE = float]
with something else
void CheckForType() [with TYPE = double]
```

Explanation:
`std::enable_if` has a second template parameter which is used as return type, if the first parameter of it will be `true`. As this, you can use that type here. As you can see, the function `CheckForType` is called with this defined type for `X` from the SFINAE expression.

Comment: Makes sense. I got confused with nameless and default parameter..thanks

Comment: But if i explicitly use an identifier instead of nameless parameter and i specify its value as well while using it outside, will the substitution for evaluating default value still be executed?

Comment: @AbhishekTripathi: Done!

Comment: What I meant to ask was if my template is like this 

template<typename  T,
 typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type>
 class Fraction{
.....}

and I use it like 

Fraction<std::string, std::string> frac();

where I explicitly specify the second argument as well, then in that case the default argument will not be evaluated and hence it is compiled successfully. It is only if we don't explicitly use the second parameter that the default argument is evaluated and the substitution fails for invalid types.

Answer (score 1):

An example :

```
//for enum types.
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum_v<T>, int>::type = 0>
void Foo(T value)
{
  //stuff..
}
```

I only want this `Foo` to be picked if `T` is an enum type. We can achieve this using the rule of Substitute Failure Is Not An Error (SFINAE).

---

This rule states that if there's a failure during substitution this shouldn't be a compilation error. The compiler should only eliminate the function for this substitution.

So then, how do we make sure `Foo` is only called with an enum type? Well that's easy, we find a way to trigger a substitution failure!

If we check [cppreference for `std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) it says:

```
template< bool B, class T = void >
struct enable_if;
```

> If `B` is `true`, `std::enable_if` has a public member typedef `type`, equal
>   to `T`; otherwise, there is no member typedef.

This means, if `std::is_enum<T>::value` is `true` (which is the case for enum types for `T`) then `B` will be `true` and thus `type` will be a valid type, an `int` as specified.

If however `std::is_enum::value` is `false` then `B` will be `false` and thus `type` won't even exist. In this case the code is trying to use `::type` while it doesn't exist and thus that's a substitution error. So SFINAE kicks in and eliminates it from the candidate list.

---

The reason we use `= 0` is to provide a default template parameter value since we're not actually interested in using this type or its value, we only use it to trigger SFINAE.

Answer (score 1):

This construct is a *nameless* template parameter supplied with a default argument. Normally a template parameter would look like

```
typename <identifier> [ = <type> ]
```

but the identifier may be omitted.

You can see this construction often in SFINAE templates because it's a convenient way to enable a specialisation if and only if some condition holds, or if some piece of code is valid. Thus one can often see

```
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if<(some-constexpr-involving-T)>::type> ...
```

If the expression happens to evaluate to true, all is well: `std::enable_if<true>::type` is just `void`, and we have a good working template specialisation.

Now if the expression above happens to be false, `std::enable_if<false>` doesn't have a member named `type`, Substitution Failure (the SF in SFINAE) happens, and the template specialisation is not considered.

And here the role of tge parameter ends. It is not used for anything in the template itself, so it doesn't need a name.

Comment: You raised a good point about omitting the identifier. Thats where I was struggling. So if i dont omit and use identifier as well with the default argument and in my driver code I call  X<t1, t2>, will there still be a substitution coz now i m providing the second argument as well so technically it shouldn't evaluate the defauly argument

Comment: The identifier is not needed but you can still supply it if you want, it will affect nothing at all. But you should NOT provide the argument when you instantiate. In many cased you cannot do that because it only appears only in template specialisations, not in the main template. You only supply arguments for the main template.